# how to know model's input size in onnx?

Tags: pytorch, onnx

The size of the input is not specified in the pytorch. Just size the kernel to make the output. The WinMLDashboard shows the width and height of the image input. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean when you serialize the network from pytorch to onnx? Because when you export from pytorch you need to define the size of the input as per [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html)

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(10, 3, 224, 224, device='cuda')
model = torchvision.models.alexnet(pretrained=True).cuda()
input_names = [ "actual_input_1" ] 
output_names = [ "output1" ]

torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "alexnet.onnx", verbose=True, 
input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names)
```

Comment: thank u, Why wasn't I thinking about it? I'm so stupid.
Do you have any good references to run onnx with c++?

Comment: If you have nvidia hardware your best bet is to use TensorRT to load the onnx network. That would give you the fastest output, but onnx has a runtime engine: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime , you can use it from C to run your inferences.